# Observable coming from firebase is not iterable and is causing the infamous differ error

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, observable, iterable

Hello I am getting an error that is causing the route not to render. I thought you could unwrap an observable into an interable using the async pipe but this error makes me think that's not happening for some reason. Observables confuse me sometimes though. What am I doing wrong?  Do I need to map this to an array first?

Error:

```
 MyOrdersComponent.html:5 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'https://oshop-c71db.firebaseio.com/orders' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
        at NgForOf.ngOnChanges (common.js:2570)
        at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12348)
        at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13876)
        at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13819)
        at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14712)
        at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14653)
        at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (MyOrdersComponent.html:5)
        at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14638)
        at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13785)
        at callViewAction (core.js:14136)
```

Template:

```
   <h1>My Orders</h1>

    <p *ngFor="let order of this.orders$ | async">{{ order.datePlaced | date}}</p>

    <p class="card-text">You currently have 0 orders placed.</p>

    <table class="table table-hover table-striped ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Order Placed</th>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th>Ship To</th>
                <th>Order Number</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let order of this.orders$ | async">
                <td></td>
                <td>{{ order.datePlaced | date}}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Component:

```
  import { AuthService } from './../auth.service';
    import { OrderService } from './../order.service';
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-orders',
    templateUrl: './my-orders.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-orders.component.css']
})
export class MyOrdersComponent {
    orders$;

    constructor(
        private authService: AuthService,
        private orderService: OrderService) {

        this.orders$ = authService.user$.map(u => orderService.getOrdersByUser(u.uid));
        // console.log(this.orders$);
    }
}
```

Order Service:

```
 import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { CartService } from './cart.service';

    @Injectable()
    export class OrderService {
        constructor(
            private db: AngularFireDatabase,
            private cartService: CartService
        ) { }

        async placeOrder(order) {
            const result = await this.db.list('/orders').push(order);
            this.cartService.clearCart();
            return result;
        }

        getOrders() {
            return this.db.list('/orders');
        }

        // getOrdersByUser(userId: string) {
        //     return this.db.list('/orders').$ref.orderByChild('userId');
        // }
        // getOrdersByUser(userId: string) {
        //     return this.db.list('/orders'.
        //         ref => ref.orderByChild('userId').equalTo(userId));
        // }
        getOrdersByUser(userId: string) {
            return this.db.list('/orders').$ref.orderByChild('userId').equalTo(userId);

        }

    }
```

Comment: It would be easier to give a definitive answer if we could see the relevant parts of `OrderService`. Can you add them to the question?

Comment: most definitely, ill put them at the bottom

Comment: You know I kinda let that getordersbyuser function without much confidence in it... thats probably whats coming back to bite me in the ass now.... that equalTo is not supposed to be there now that i look at it

Comment: `$ref` is perplexing documentation doesn't discuss it. The types are not very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The name `getOrdersByUserId` implies that you are binding to either an `Observable<Observable<T>>`, an `Observable<Promise<T>>`, or an `Observable<T[]>`.

Therefore, you need to call `flatMap` instead of `map`.

As discussed in comments, this could also be achieved by using `concatMap` or `switchMap`.

Also note that `flatMap` is an alias for `mergeMap` (or is it the other way around) so you might alternately use that function. Do be consistent using only `mergeMap` or `flatMap` and not both within a project as there already enough names for these ops.

Comment: from RxJS 5, `flatMap` is alias of `mergeMap`, also we can use `concatMap` or `switchMap`, ...

Comment: @TiepPhan indeed there are many names for this operation. I would just as soon call it `SelectMany`. `concatMap` and `switchMap` are slightly different but they will behave effectively the same way here because there's only one element in the source. I find the term `mergeMap` to be disconcerting since it works for things that are most definitely not mergeable.

Comment: yeap, I know that.I just wanna give other solutions for deal with above situation.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I used to have switchMap there but I would get this linting error and magically it went away when i changed it to map   Argument of type '(u: User) => Query' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: User, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'Query' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
    Type 'Query' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike<{}>'.
      Property 'length' is missing in type 'Query'.

Comment: @imnickvaughn be careful. Having to specify the parameter type of a callback function usually means you are doing something wrong. It can also hide errors. Note there is a difference between typechecker and linter errors as well.